# React-Native won't update despite changing the React-Native dependency in packages.json

Tags: react-native

In my react-native project, I have updated the react-native dependency to:

```
"react-native": "^0.30.0"
```

and then I run `npm install`.

However, after running this, and checking the react-native version in command line, it is still saying I have version 0.28.  What is happening and how can I update to the latest version of react-native (while making sure the other packages and dependencies work with it).  Thank you.

These are errors I'm seeing:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-S" "react-native@0.30.0"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/*********/f8app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -S react-native@0.30.0`

and

`react-native upgrade`

`react-native link`

Then check that everything is ok

Comment: `rnpm` is alredy built in react-native. Update your rn cli using `npm i react-native-cli -g` and then you can do `react-native link`.

Comment: Yeah, but `rnpm` is now `react-native link`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there were no errors during installation? I will suggest just doing `rm -rf /node_modules && npm i` and you can be sure that you have the newest version installed.

Comment: when I'm running: npm install -S react-native@0.30.0: I get the error: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded